# Migrate Database of Django 1.4 application to Django 1.8 version

Tags: django, django-models, django-migrations

We have migrated the Django 1.4 application to Django 1.8 successfully. The Django 1.4 version of applicaiton is still in use in production until we go live with Django 1.8. The problem is that lots of data have been updated on production server which needs to be migrated to version 1.8. Is there any way I can migrate the data from database of 1.4 to 1.8 except manually doing that? Note that the model/database columns are different in both the version.

Can anybody suggest some good options ?

Thanks.

Comment: this doesn't make sense: The problem is that lots of data have been updated on production server which needs to be migrated to 1.8 version on local enviroment. - I think you mean you have your local environment on 1.8 and production on 1.4 right?

Comment: have you manually renamed any columns or tables in your database?

Comment: Yes Luke, that's right. Locally I've 1.8 and on production it is 1.4. No I didn't rename any column but you might be knowing that the model structures have been changed in 1.8 and so the database. Hope it makes sense. Thanks.

Comment: when you say 'the model structures have been changed' have you actually changed any of your models? i.e. have you edited any of the model fields in any of your models.py files?

Comment: Yes some models. Please guide me further what would be the best approach ?

Answer (score 2):

**Required pre-reading**

Django migrations:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/django-admin/#makemigrations-app-label

Assuming you were using South:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/migrations/#upgrading-from-south

**Getting Started**

Firstly dump your local database I prefer using mysql/postgres/whatever docs for this rather than using ./manage.py dumpdata.

You will also want to dump your production database as well just for safekeeping.

Next in your local environment I would dump the database and create a new database.

Then I would test that all your migrations actually work on a blank database.
These are the instructions for django 1.8

```
./manage.py makemirgrations

./manage.py migrate
```

That will help show up if any migrations are in an inconsistent state operating from a blank slate. If you encounter any errors they should be fixed first.

Given that works, now I would test that your migrations actually work against your production data.

So drop your local database, create a fresh one then load the production dump in.

If the tables are already configured correctly (i.e. they are in an up to date state in your production database) then you will need to fake all migrations.

```
./manage.py migrate --fake <appname>
```

However given that you have changed some models since upgrading to 1.8 in your local environment, then you might need to fake only some of the migrations. This could be the tricky part depending on the timing of when you upgraded and when you created the migrations.

Because django 1.7 will just create an initial migration for each app, you may need to actually break up the migration for some apps. That is, instead of 0001_initial you might need to manually break up that migration into 2 components:
1. a migration to match the current state of your production database
2. a migration to match any additional changes you have made to your model since then.

One way to do this is to checkout your first commit once you had django 1.8 working correctly locally then run

```
./manage.py makemigrations
```

then commit that

then go forward to your latest commit then run

```
./manage.py makemigrations
```

Now you should have 2+ migrations in each app that you have modified since upgrading to django 1.8.

Then you can fake initial on those apps that have 2+ new migrations for django 1.8

```
./manage.py migrate --fake-initial app1 app2
```

and the rest just

```
./manage.py migrate app3 app4
```

Now run your tests to confirm everything is working locally.

If you have changed migrations you will again want to test locally against a blank database to test that they work smoothly

Once that is working, record the 'migrate' commands that you used - then deploy your app to production and run just those migration commands once you have upgraded to django 1.8 on your server.

**After Successful Completion**

1. Take new dumps of your local and production databases
2. Uninstall South (assuming you had it installed before) from local and production environments

I'm sure there are a couple of holes in the above but hopefully that gives you the gist of what you need to do.

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed answer. I'll try all above and let you know. Thanks once again.